# Quotient of two geometric Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Given $X=X_t$, $Y=Y_t$ and
\begin{align}
      dX_t &= μX_t\,dt +  σX_t\,dB_t,
\\
      dY_t &= σY_t\,dt + μY_t\,dB_t,
\\  
      V_t &= \frac{X_t}{Y_t}
\end{align}
How to calculate $dV_t$?

I'm new to SDE and calculus as well, so I'm not sure if I solved it wrong or not...

Please help, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a few minutes to edit your question and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it more readable.  Also, you mentioned that you're not sure you solved it wrong or not, please include those details as well.

Comment: Is the Brownian motion the same in both equations?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes it's the same

Comment: DMcMor: Ok i will edit now

Comment: Can you apply Ito's formula?

Answer (score 2):

It is often more simple to compute the derivative in a product formula instead of in a quotient formula. In the product formula for $X=YV$ you get, in infinitesimal increments,
$$
dX_t=d(V_tY_t)=(V_t+dV_t)(Y_t+dY_t)-V_tY_t=V_t\,dY_t+Y_t\,dV_t+dV_t\,dY_t
$$
While the last term as infinitesimal increment is random, this randomness is vanishingly small around a trend $d\langle V,Y\rangle_t$, which is the quadratic variation or correlation of the two processes. If $dV_t=a(V)dt+b(V)dB_t$, then $d⟨V,Y⟩_t=b(V)μY_t\,dt$. So let's insert all known equations
$$
X_t(μ\,dt+σ\,dB_t)=V_tY_t(σ\,dt+μ\,dBt)+Y_t\,dV_t+b(V)μY_t\,dt\\
V_t(μ-σ)(dt-dB_t)=a(V_t)\,dt+b(V_t)\,dB_t+μb(V)\,dt
$$
Comparing coefficients gives
\begin{align}
a(V_t)+μb(V_t)&=(μ-σ)V_t
\\
b(V_t)&=-(μ-σ)V_t
\\
\implies
a(V_t)&=(μ-σ)(1+μ)V_t
\end{align}

---

For a formal derivation of these results use the Ito theorem on transformations of stochastic processes which gives the same formula without mucking around with infinitesimals.

---

One could also use the solution formulas for geometric Brownian motions
$$
X_t=X_0e^{(μ+σ^2/2)t+σB_t}\\
Y_t=Y_0e^{(σ+μ^2/2)t+μB_t}\\
V_t=V_0e^{((μ-σ)-(μ^2-σ^2)/2)t-(μ-σ)B_t}
$$
which directly implies, as again a geometric Brownian motion,
$$
dV_t=[(μ-σ)(1-(μ+σ)/2)-(μ-σ)^2/2]V_t\,dt-(μ-σ)V_t\,dB_t.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Note\begin{align}
dV &= \frac{dV}{dX}dX+ \frac{dV}{dY}dY 
+\frac12 \frac{d^2V}{dX^2}(dX)^2
 +\frac12 \frac{d^2V}{dY^2}(dY)^2
+\frac{d^2V}{dXdY}(dXdY)\\
&= \frac{1}{Y}dX- \frac{X}{Y^2}dY 
+\frac12 \cdot0\cdot(dX)^2
 +\frac{X}{Y^3}(dY)^2
- \frac{1}{Y^2}(dXdY)\\
\end{align}
Substitute $dX/X= μdt+  σdB$ and $dY/Y =σdt+ μdB$ into above to obtain
$$dV = V[\mu dt+\sigma dB - \sigma dt-\mu dB
+\mu^2(dB)^2- \mu\sigma (dB)(dB)] \\
= (\mu-\sigma+\mu^2-\mu\sigma)Vdt + (\sigma-\mu)VdB
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!